# Conform on-the-fly to PEP8 using flycheck on emacs

Tags: python, emacs, flycheck

I unpack [flycheck](http://www.flycheck.org/en/27/_downloads/flycheck.html) to `~/.` and put the following lines in `~/.emacs`:

```
;; (package-initialize)
(setq load-path (cons "~/flycheck-20170415.1006" load-path))
(require 'flycheck)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
```

Starting Emacs 24.5.1 I get:

```
File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, let-alist
```

With Emacs 25.1.1 I get:

```
File error: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, dash
```

(These errors do not change if I uncomment `(package-initialize)`. Emacs 25 now inserts `(package-initialize)`, nudging those of us with a long setup to adapt.)

My (subsequent) aim is to conform Python code on-the-fly to PEP8. Once the problem above is resolved, I'll add

```
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin")))
```

to this brief `~/.emacs` (`/opt/..2.7/bin` is where MacPorts put `flake8`), but there is apparently an issue before I even specify the programming language.

**Update**

This is far more painful than I expected. Flycheck is heavy-handed about being installed through packages, and incorporating the steps described [here](http://www.flycheck.org/en/27/_downloads/flycheck.html#Installation) to my usual `~/.emacs` leads to the notorious

```
load-with-code-conversion: Symbol’s value as variable is void: <!DOCTYPE
```

error. (I'm pretty sure I have no HTML files hiding under a `.el` extension.)

**Update2**

Uh.. I stand corrected! Some `dash.el` made its way to my usual elisp directory, and flycheck depends on it, but it was indeed an HTML file.

Comment: What do you see when you do `M-x flycheck-verify-setup` in a Python buffer?

Comment: @elethan Thanks. Once again I am reminded that it's pointless to attempt to debug an Emacs problem without working with an isolated and minimal `.emacs`. Running `eval-region` on a few lines is misleading. I've revised the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Flycheck` depends on [`dash`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el), [`let-alist`](https://github.com/leanprover/emacs-dependencies/blob/master/let-alist/let-alist.el), and [`seq`](https://github.com/NicolasPetton/seq.el).

Download the files

```
  84766  dash.el
 381142  flycheck.el
   6136  let-alist.el
  17589  seq-24.el
  17684  seq-25.el
   1540  seq.el
```

and put them in `~/.concise-elisp`. You need three files for seq because it has alternative implementations for Emacs 24 & 25.

Put the following lines in your `~/.emacs`:

```
;; Even if you are not using packages, you need the following
;; commented-out line, or else Emacs 25 will insert one for you.
;; (package-initialize)

(setq load-path (cons "~/.concise-elisp" load-path))
(require 'flycheck)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin")))
```

The last line points to where MacPorts would have put `flake8`. Flake8 is one of the programs to which flycheck delegates PEP8 checking.

Next exercise: Hook `flycheck` just for Python (and perhaps C/C++/Java/JS/..). In particular, don't worry about making elisp files kosher. Selectively activate `flycheck` for languages as needed.